# Compute 2^x where x is the user input

Tags: python, exception

I have tried to build exceptions for this problem like asked in the problem below. Unfortunately I can't make it work. I would greatly appreciate any input whatsoever. Thank you in advance.

**Compute 2^x where x is the user input. x should be greater than or equal to 5 and less than or equal to 25. If the user input is not an integer then raise an exception. Create custom exceptions and raise if x is less than 5 and greater than 25. Then add the digits of 2x. For example if user inputs 6, then find 26 = 64, so the sum of the digits is 6 + 4 = 10.**

```
import sys

i = int(raw_input("Please provide a value for x (between 5 and 25): " ))

try:

x = int(i)

except ValueError as v:
    print 'You did not enter a valid integer',v

except NotAValidValue as n:
    if x < 5 or x > 25:
        print 'Your entry is not valid. Please provide a number between 5 and 25',n
    sys.exit(0)

    exp = 2 ** x

print(exp)
```

Again, Thank you so much for giving this your time.

Comment: Stack overflow is not here for us to do your homework, try something and if you run into a specific issue or question we will help you. What have you tried so far that isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example, it's written to be executed on python 2.x:

```
import sys

try:
    x = int(raw_input("Please provide a value for x (between 5 and 25): "))

    if x < 5 or x > 25:
        print('Your entry is not valid {0}.' +
              'Please provide a number between 5 and 25'.format(x))
    else:
        exp = 2 ** x
        print(exp)
except ValueError as v:
    print('You did not enter a valid integer {0}'.format(v))
```

One advice though, try carefully to read & understand all the code and start
tweaking it here and there to make it yours. You won't learn too much using other's code 'as it is', next time try to be more specific asking which specific parts of your code don't understand :)

Have fun learning python!

Comment: try:
    x = int(raw_input("Please provide a value for x (between 5 and 25): "))

    if x < 5 or x > 25:
        print('Your entry is not valid. ' +
              'Please provide a number between 5 and 25'.format(x))
        
    else:
        exp = 2 ** x
        print "Solution of 2^x for this input is: ", exp
        digits = [ int(char) for char in str(exp) ]
        total = sum( digits )
        print "The sum of the digits is:", total
        
except ValueError as v:
    print('You did not enter a valid integer!! {0}'.format(v))

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will keep in mind everything you mentioned in your response. I finished the problem successfully.

Comment: @Jared Glad to hear that, btw the best way to thanks here in StackOverflow is accepting the answer it helped you the most

Answer (score 0):

The way you define custom exceptions in python is as shown below. You need to define each custom exception as a subclass of the Exception class. You can then catch your own custom exceptions with a catch-except block.

```
import sys

class TooSmallExc(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        Exception.__init__(self,"The number is less than 5") 

class TooLargeExc(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        Exception.__init__(self,"The number is greater than 25") 

print 'How are you?'
i = raw_input("Please provide a value for x (between 5 and 25): " )

try:
    x = int(i)
    if x<5:
    raise TooSmallExc
    if x>25:
    raise TooLargeExc
except ValueError:
    print 'I just caught a ValueError exception, which is a Python built-in exception'
except TooSmallExc:
    print 'I just caught a custom exception that I made for integers less than 5'
except TooLargeExc:
    print 'I just caught a custom exception that I made for integers greater than 25'
```